# How to install / configure jsc-android-buildscripts in appcelerator/titanium app?

Tags: android, titanium, momentjs, appcelerator, luxon

I'm using Luxon library (https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/install.html) into Appcelerator project but to have full timezone functionality in Android App I need to install jsc-android-buildscripts (https://github.com/react-native-community/jsc-android-buildscripts).

How can import and configure it in my project? Someone can help me?

Comment: I tried install it with npm install --save jsc-android and include it by var Intl = require('jsc-android'); but it doesn't works.

Comment: fyi, treat titanium is a javascript/node application, not native android in terms of developing for it

Answer (score 0):

Moment.js is a build in feature in Titanium. Using moment-timezones is really easy as well.

Put the moment-timezone library into `/app/lib/moment-timezone.js` and change only 1 thing. Inside moment-timezone is a `require('moment')`. Change this to `require('alloy/moment')` and then whenever in your app you want to use the library you only have to require that module using `require('moment-timezone);`

Comment: I don't know if I will be able to do everything with moment.js instead of luxon.js, however if there is no way to import jsc.android I will try to do it. Obviously everything works great on iOS. : - /

Comment: have you tried just requiring this? https://moment.github.io/luxon/amd/luxon.js Put it in the `/app/lib` directory and require it. I see no dependencies so it should work out of the box

Comment: Ok I'll try, I installed it with "npm". The strange thing is that with Android some calculations with the timezone return null without any error. Searching on Google I found similar reports for those who use React Native (https://github.com/moment/luxon/issues?utf8=✓&q=android). From these reports I went back to the installation documentation of luxon where they write about to use jsc-android-buildscripts to fix it.

Comment: Going further, maybe I understood the problem if we have nothing to do with Reactive Native. I may need the international support of nodejs (full-icu). I can try to install it but I don't know if I can make it work. See the Node section https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/install.html